# what is a "normal" netstat -a -b result supposed to look like on a fresh windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows-10, netstat

I just reinstalled windows 10 by choosing "Reset My PC" in the settings and telling it to erase the disk. When it finished few things run. Edge crashes. Settings won't come up. File Explorer works. Device Manager works. Powershell works.

I did a `netstat -a -b` and I see these results

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> netstat -a -b

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7790           DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 [KillerService.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
  Schedule
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
  EventLog
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 [spoolsv.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49800          DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49932          DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    10.0.1.19:139          DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    10.0.1.19:5040         DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
  CDPSvc
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    10.0.1.19:49925        52.230.84.0:https      ESTABLISHED
  WpnService
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    10.0.1.19:49992        52.230.84.0:https      ESTABLISHED
  WpnService
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50098        a-0001:https           TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50103        13.107.140.254:https   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50111        13.107.54.254:https    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50115        23.102.64.11:https     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50120        117.18.237.29:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50122        52.148.90.11:https     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50123        52.148.90.11:https     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50124        52.151.59.184:https    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50125        111.221.29.254:https   ESTABLISHED
  DiagTrack
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50126        gap-prime-finance:https  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50128        gap-prime-finance:https  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50129        52.175.23.79:https     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50130        111.221.29.254:https   ESTABLISHED
  DiagTrack
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50134        a110-232-153-176:http  ESTABLISHED
  DoSvc
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50135        a110-232-153-170:http  ESTABLISHED
  DoSvc
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50137        a110-232-153-176:http  ESTABLISHED
  DoSvc
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    10.0.1.19:50138        a110-232-153-170:http  ESTABLISHED
  DoSvc
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7790         DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49988  ESTABLISHED
 [KillerService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49668        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49669  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49669        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49668  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49670        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49671  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49671        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49670  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49672        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49673  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49673        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49672  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49674        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49675  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49675        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49674  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49676        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49677  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49677        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49676  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49678        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49679  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49679        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49678  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49680        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49681  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49681        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49680  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49684        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49685  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49685        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49684  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49686        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49687  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49687        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49686  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49688        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49689  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49689        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49688  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49690        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49691  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49691        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49690  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49692        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49693  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49693        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49692  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49694        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49695  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49695        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49694  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49698        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49699  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49699        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49698  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49700        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49701  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49701        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49700  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49702        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49703  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49703        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49702  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49704        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49705  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49705        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49704  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49706        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49707  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49707        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49706  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49708        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49709  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49709        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49708  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49710        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49711  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49711        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49710  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49712        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49713  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49713        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49712  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49714        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49715  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49715        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49714  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49716        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49717  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49717        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49716  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49718        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49719  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49719        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49718  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49720        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49721  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49721        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49720  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49722        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49723  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49723        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49722  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49724        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49725  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49725        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49724  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49728        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49729  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49729        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49728  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49730        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49731  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49731        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49730  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49732        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49733  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49733        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49732  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49734        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49735  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49735        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49734  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49736        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49737  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49737        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49736  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49738        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49739  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49739        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49738  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49740        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49741  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49741        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49740  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49742        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49743  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49743        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49742  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49744        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49745  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49745        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49744  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49746        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49747  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49747        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49746  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49748        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49749  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49749        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49748  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49750        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49751  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49751        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49750  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49752        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49753  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49753        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49752  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49754        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49755  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49755        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49754  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49756        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49757  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49757        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49756  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49758        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49759  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49759        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49758  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49760        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49761  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49761        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49760  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49762        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49763  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49763        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49762  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49764        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49765  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49765        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49764  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49766        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49767  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49767        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49766  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49768        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49769  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49769        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49768  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49770        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49771  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49771        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49770  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49772        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49773  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49773        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49772  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49774        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49775  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49775        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49774  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49776        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49777  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49777        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49776  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49778        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49779  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49779        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49778  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49780        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49781  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49781        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49780  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49782        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49783  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49783        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49782  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49784        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49785  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49785        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49784  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49786        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49787  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49787        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49786  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49788        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49789  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49789        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49788  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49790        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49791  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49791        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49790  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49792        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49793  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49793        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49792  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49794        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49795  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49795        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49794  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49796        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49797  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49797        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49796  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49798        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49799  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49799        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49798  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49801        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49802  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49802        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49801  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49803        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49804  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49804        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49803  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49805        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49806  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49806        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49805  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49807        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49808  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49808        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49807  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49809        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49810  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49810        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49809  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49811        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49812  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49812        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49811  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49813        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49814  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49814        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49813  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49815        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49816  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49816        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49815  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49819        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49820  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49820        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49819  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49821        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49822  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49822        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49821  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49823        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49824  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49824        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49823  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49827        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49828  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49828        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49827  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49829        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49830  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49830        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49829  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49831        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49832  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49832        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49831  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49833        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49834  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49834        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49833  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49837        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49838  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49838        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49837  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49839        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49840  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49840        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49839  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49841        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49842  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49842        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49841  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49843        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49844  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49844        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49843  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49845        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49846  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49846        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49845  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49847        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49848  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49848        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49847  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49849        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49850  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49850        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49849  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49851        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49852  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49852        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49851  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49853        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49854  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49854        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49853  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49857        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49858  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49858        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49857  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49859        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49860  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49860        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49859  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49861        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49862  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49862        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49861  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49863        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49864  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49864        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49863  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49865        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49866  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49866        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49865  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49867        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49868  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49868        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49867  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49869        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49870  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49870        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49869  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49871        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49872  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49872        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49871  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49873        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49874  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49874        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49873  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49877        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49878  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49878        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49877  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49879        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49880  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49880        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49879  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49883        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49884  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49884        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49883  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49885        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49886  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49886        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49885  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49887        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49888  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49888        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49887  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49891        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49892  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49892        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49891  ESTABLISHED
 [LegacyCsLoaderService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49907        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49908  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49908        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49907  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49911        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49912  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49912        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49911  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49913        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49914  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49914        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49913  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49915        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49916  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49916        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:49915  ESTABLISHED
 [IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49988        DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:7790   ESTABLISHED
 [NetworkManager.exe]
  TCP    [::]:135               DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:445               DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:49664             DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:49665             DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
  Schedule
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49666             DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
  EventLog
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49667             DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 [spoolsv.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49800             DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:49932             DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    [::1]:49950            DESKTOP-U8NHDTN:0      LISTENING
 [jhi_service.exe]
  TCP    [2002:db62:367e:0:9d05:63a3:21d9:3cfc]:50136  [2606:2800:147:120f:30c:1ba0:fc6:3000]:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    [2002:db62:367e:0:9d05:63a3:21d9:3cfc]:50139  [2606:2800:147:120f:30c:1ba0:fc6:3000]:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    [2002:db62:367e:0:9d05:63a3:21d9:3cfc]:50144  [2606:2800:147:120f:30c:1ba0:fc6:3000]:http  TIME_WAIT
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5050           *:*
  CDPSvc
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    10.0.1.19:137          *:*
 Can not obtain ownership information
  UDP    10.0.1.19:138          *:*
 Can not obtain ownership information
  UDP    127.0.0.1:49664        *:*
  iphlpsvc
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [fe80::2446:34f3:f5ff:feec%12]:546  *:*
  Dhcp
 [svchost.exe]
```

I'm not at all an expert on what to expect from netstat but something seems fishy. What are all those seemingly random IP addresses? What is `gap-prime-finance`. Why are there like 50+ `IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe` entries and also a ton of `LegacyCsLoaderService.exe` entries?

So I thought I'd ask what should a "normal" fresh install show? Note I have installed zero software nor updates although I have no idea what Windows itself did when resetting. Winver says Windows 10 Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.371)

Comment: regarding 'IntelTechnologyAccessService.exe'. since the connection is on 127.0.0.1, it's Interprocess Communication (two processes on your box, talking to each other using the network stack as the intermediary). the LegacyCsLoaderService is related to the IntelTechnologyAccessService.

Comment: gap-prime-finance is MS Singapore.